# active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in `method_missing' error occurs when I upgrade my rails 2.3.3 project to 2.3.17

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

Our rails project version is 2.3.3. Recently, however, we decided to upgrade rails version to 2.3.17 to patch the security holes.

But after upgrade my rails gem, I got the following error.
Is there anyone whoh had a same problem?

```
benjamins-iMac:webapp benjamin$ script/server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.17 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/rails-2.3.17/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
/Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activerecord-2.3.17/lib/active_record/associations.rb:48: warning: already initialized constant HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasManyReflection
/Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in `method_missing': undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/rails-2.3.17/lib/initializer.rb:445:in `initialize_database_middleware'
  from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/rails-2.3.17/lib/initializer.rb:182:in `process'
  from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/rails-2.3.17/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
  from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/rails-2.3.17/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
  from /Users/benjamin/clue/webapp/config/environment.rb:6
  from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
  from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
  from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
  from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
  from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/rails-2.3.17/lib/commands/server.rb:84
  from script/server:3:in `require'
  from script/server:3
benjamins-iMac:webapp benjamin$
```

And the `ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/rails-2.3.17/lib/initializer.rb:445`'s code is

```
ActionController::Base.session_store.name == 'ActiveRecord::SessionStore'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem.
The answer was at here.
http://johnpwood.net/2009/09/04/disabling-sessions-in-rails-2-3-4/

Answer (score 0):

The error is never enough information to go off of alone. however, so simple things, did you run:  `sudo rake gems:install` already?

Also, the database columns must be present for your ActiveRecord models to pick up. If the initial state is "no-database" and subsequent rake tasks call on models, then it would choke on nils. I see `environment.rb` in the stack trace, so I assume it got that far...

So you should note that if you are upgrading from older version to the newer one then `environment.rb` file also needs to be changed apart from others. See carefully the changes that you need to done specially the `initializer` tasks as all the problem lies there according to the error log.